# Is there a way to access an array from a different method?

Tags: java, arrays

I am struggling with a question where I have to access an array that I have initialized under the main method.

*How would I go about accessing the array(random[]) under the method 'isLower'?*

**My errors:**

```
Example3.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
            for(int i = 0;i<random.length;i++){
                            ^
  symbol:   variable numbers
  location: class Example3
Example3.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
                    System.out.print(random[i] + " ");
                                     ^
```

**My Code:**

```
static void isLower(){
    int freq = 0;

    if(random[i]>='a'&&random[i]<='z'){//if lowercase
        freq++;
        return false;
    }
    else if(random[i]>='A'&&random[i]<='Z'){//if uppercase
        return true;
    }


}

public static void main(String [] args){
    int num;
    char random [] = new char[1000];

    for(int i = 0;i<1000;i++){
        num = (int)(Math.random()*((126-32)+1))+32;
        random[i] = (char)num;

    }
```

**The question that I am trying to complete is worded as such:**

Write a Java program that initializes a character array with 1000 printable
random characters from the ASCII table. Your program should then process
the array to find the frequency of lowercase values. Your solution should use a
programmer defined method called ***isLower*** that takes a character as it’s
parameter and returns ***true*** if the parameter is uppercase and ***false*** if it is
lowercase.

Comment: `random` defined in `main` is not accessible in the `isLower` method. You have to pass it to the method. Also `void` is not compatible with returning `boolean`.

Comment: Generally, if you need a method to do something with an array, you should make your method take an array as input parameter. However, if you read your assignment again, your method does not need to take an array, it should take a single character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the whole array again, in the method, since the problem is asking only for a single character, what you should do instead, is to  pass the character, as parameter and return only a boolean, every time you have a lowerCase character.
**This should work:**

```
static boolean isLower(char character){

    if(character>='a'&&character<='z'){//if lowercase
        return true;
    } else {//if uppercase or any other character different than a letter
        return false;
    }
}
```

**In Main method**
Just call the isLower function, and verify the boolean result, there you will count the frequency, not in the other method.

According to your problem description, that should be the fix.

Comment: Just my personal opinion: answering homework questions with the solution as code, without further explanation, might do more harm than help. Of course, it is up to OP as to what to do with the information presented, but...

Comment: @domsson, I edited my answer, explaining how to accomplish his work, without giving the complete answer.

Comment: Nice, appreciated (and hopefully, so does OP).

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to declare it like this:

`static void isLower(char[] random)`

and call it like this:

`isLower(random);`

Answer (score 0):

That array is out of scope of that method. A easy fix would be to make it a field and declare it in the Class level. (If you're going to use that array in main() it needs to be static though)

You could also pass it to your method but the assignment says isLower should just take a char, not an array!

```
Class YourClass {
char random [];
    static void isLower(){
    // Populate/assign your array here
    ....
    }
    public static void main(String [] args){
    ....
    }

}
```